# In notepad++, is there a way to find how many files are opened?

Tags: notepad++

I have opened multiple files in notepad++.

I would like to know how many files were opened. Is there a way to know that?

Comment: Umm... by looking at the window or programming an application to do it? At first I only thought you meant looking at the window...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Programmatically, you can use the `NPPM_GETNBOPENFILES` message

```
NPPM_GETNBOPENFILES
The return value depends on nbType :

nbType          Meaning
ALL_OPEN_FILES  the total number of files opened in Notepad++
PRIMARY_VIEW    the number of files opened in the primary view
SECOND_VIEW     the number of files opened in the second view
```

The Notepad++ messages are listed [here.](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Messages_And_Notifications)